# can't pass id to controller in codeigniter through a button in views

Tags: php, codeigniter

so i am trying to pass id from a link i created in views to my controller method however i get the error that unidentified variable id

below is the link in view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>doctors/display_schedule/<?php echo $id['d_id']; ?>" >set schedule</a>
```

and this is the controller method:

```
public function display_schedule($d_id)
    {
        $data['id'] = $this->doctor_model->get_info_by_id($d_id);
        $this->load->view("doctors_schedule_view",$data);
    }
```

ps, if you want a look at my model inform me

Answer (score 0):

When passing data in this way, no matter what the variable names are you need to explicitly assign the variable in the controller otherwise i'll remain undefined.

Let's assume:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>doctors/display_schedule/<?php echo $id['d_id']; ?>" >set schedule</a>
```

points to `doctors/display_schedule/1234`

So, if you want to use `1234` you need to enable the URL helper and add this in the `display_schedule` method in your controller:

`$d_id = $this->uri->segment(3);`

This way, whatever was passed to the controller in the third uri segment will be assigned to `$d_id` in the controller.

BE AWARE that you need to sanitize the input after assigning it to the variable in order to prevent malicious uses like code injecting and whatnot.

Comment: Did you load the url helper? it's required for `$this->uri->segment(3)` to work... can you update your code?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try,

Controller:

```
public function display_schedule($d_id)
    {
        $getData = $this->doctor_model->get_info_by_id($d_id);
        $data['id'] = $getData['d_id'];
        $this->load->view("doctors_schedule_view",$data);
    }
```

View:

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>doctors/display_schedule/<?=$id;?>" >set schedule</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This: Set `true`

```
$this->load->view("doctors_schedule_view",$data,true);
```